# Websphere Liberty server.xml in RAD gives cvc-complex-type.2.4.a on keystore

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty, server.xml

We installed WebSphere Liberty and I added the server to RAD/Eclipse. The server.xml was created and had errors right out of the box with the featuremanager node complaining that there was no keystore.  So I added the keystore as I saw in an online example:

But that node ALSO gets an error:

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'keyStore'. One of '{include, variable, 
 featureManager, executor, config, fileset, logging, zosLogging}' is expected.

So if keystore isn't valid, but it's required...what to do?

Here's the full server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
  <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- This template enables security. To get the full use of all the capabilities, a keystore and user registry are required. -->

<!-- For the keystore, default keys are generated and stored in a keystore. To provide the keystore password, generate an
    encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it below in the password attribute of the keyStore element. 
    Then uncomment the keyStore element. -->
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="keyStorePwd"/>

<!--For a user registry configuration, configure your user registry. For example, configure a basic user registry using the
    basicRegistry element. Specify your own user name below in the name attribute of the user element. For the password, 
    generate an encoded password using bin/securityUtility encode and add it in the password attribute of the user element.
    Then uncomment the user element. -->
<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">
    <!-- <user name="yourUserName" password="" />  -->
</basicRegistry>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
        httpPort="9080"
        httpsPort="9443" />

<!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
 </server>
```

Comment: Maybe you are using outdated RAD/Eclipse version? That `server.xml` should be fine.

Comment: @Gas - Thanks for the quick response.  I'm using Liberty 16.0.0.2 and RAD 9.6.1.

Comment: 16.* is very old. Use 19.* or 18.* WebSphere Liberty version and see if it will help.

Comment: @Gas - We went to 19.0.0.6 this morning.  It hasn't changed anything.  I can turn off validation on the project, but that's not the right move.

Comment: When you updated the runtime, did you refresh the server metadata cached by Eclipse?  Preferences | Server | Runtime Environments | select the 19006 runtime | Edit... | Advanced options | Refresh.

Comment: @FRowe - That does clear that problem.  Thanks.

Comment: For others in the future with the same issue, I've created an answer to make this easier to find, you would please accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the runtime, you may need to refresh the server metadata cached by Eclipse.  Go to Preferences | Server | Runtime Environments | select the 19006 runtime | Edit... | Advanced options | Refresh.